# Recursive javascript function is not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying recursion.

I just want the output to be the result of multiplying the input by 2: `output = 2*input`.

It should be like this, why is it not working?

```
function fE(f) {
  if(f < 0){
    return 1;}
  else{
  return f + fE(f);}


}

console.log(fE(3)); // output 6
console.log(fE(6)); // 12
```

Comment: multiply is *, you are doing add (+)

Comment: @JaromandaX edited

Comment: You'll get infinite recursion if the recursive call simply passes the same `f` argument through. (Plus it doesn't make sense to use recursion for this problem.)

Comment: then how to stop it ?

Comment: you don't need to recurse if all you want is `function fE(f) { return 2 * f; }`

Comment: why you doing it with recursive function ?

Comment: cause i had to. how to stop the function ?

Comment: The recursion does not make sense at all. You could write a factorial function (4! = 4*3*2*1 = 24) to practice recursion.

Comment: @DellWatson to make it stop, you typically decrease the argument in every recursive call so that it eventually reaches your base case (`f < 0`)

Comment: question title says "recursive not working"......however recursive is working but your function is not working and the whole logic is going in infinite loop....i couldn't get your issue at all....

Comment: `function fE(f) { return arguments.length !== 1 ? f : f + fE(f,true); }` - a pointlessly recursive way of implementing a doubling function.

Comment: @MertMetin He's trying to do it recursively for learning purposes, presumably.

Comment: sure! deleted my answer. But this is not very good example to understand recursive functions. Anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion involves a base case, which in your case is an input of zero. The answer in that case is zero. Otherwise, reduce the problem to the sum of two and the result of calling the function recursively with an argument one less. If the input is negative, return the negation of the result of the negation of the input.

```js
function fE(f) {
  if (f === 0) return 0;
  else if (f < 0) return -fE(-f);
  else return 2 + fE(f - 1);
}

console.log(fE(3)); // output 6
console.log(fE(6)); // 12
console.log(fE(-4)); // -8
```

Your code:

```
function fE(f) {
  if(f < 0){
    return 1;}
  else{
  return f + fE(f);}
}
```

has the following problems:

1. If the input is zero or less, you probably want to return zero, not one.
2. Otherwise, you want to recurse with a value of one less than the input. `fE(f)` will cause an infinite loop, right?
3. You don't want to add `f` to the result of recursing; you want to add 2, which is where you get the doubling effect.

Comment: `if (f < 0) return -fE(-f);`. Anyway, nice work with the `2 +` doubling effect - for some reason I didn't think of that and so my answer gave an example that took two numbers as input. Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Your function as shown will try to recurse infinitely, because the recursive call on the line with `f + fE(f)` passes the same value of `f` through each time, which means the `if` test on the first line will always fail.

It doesn't make any sense to implement this recursively, because you can calculate the correct result with one line of code:

```
function fE(f) { return 2 * f; }
```

Perhaps a better example of a recursive function (for learning purposes) would be a function that multiples any two numbers together via a larger number of recursive calls:

```
multiply(10, 3)  // return 30
```

...again that could easily be implemented in one line:

```
function multiply(a, b) { return a * b; }
```

...but you could do it with recursion like this:

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
  if (b === 0)
    return 0;
  else if (b === 1)
    return a;
  else if (b < 0)
    return -multiply(a, -b);
  else
    return a + multiply(a, b-1);
}

multiply(12, 4)  // 48
multiply(5, -3)  // -15
multiply(3, 0)   // 0
```

Notice that each time the function calls itself it passes a *different* value in the second argument, so that eventually the `else if (b === 1)` condition will be true and the recursion will stop. I've included a `console.log(a,b)` so that you can see for yourself what the arguments are on each call.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers from @torazaburo and @nnnnnn – they're practical and should solve your immediate problem. I'll offer some other alternatives in hope that these will help your brain think about recursive procedures in a variety of ways.

Another common recursion technique is using state variables in an auxiliary function

```js
function mult (x, y) {
  function aux (result, counter) {
    if (counter === 0)
      return result
    else
      return aux (result + x, counter - 1)
  }
  return aux (0, y)
}

console.log(mult (5, 4)) // 20
```

Here's another technique that uses continuation passing style

```js
function multk (x, y, k) {
  if (y === 0)
    k (0)
  else
    multk (x, y - 1, function (result) { k (result + x) })
}

multk (5, 4, function (result) { console.log(result) /* 20 */ })
```

And here's a nutty boiled down version that uses nothing more than primitive `+1` and primitive `-1`. It may seem complicated but I constructed it for you so that you can see how more complex recursive procedures can be built out of smaller ones. If you can follow this code, it should help you gain a greater understanding of recursion.

(I added some `console.log` lines so you can get a better visualization of what's happening. You wouldn't want to leave these in your code.)

```js
function add1 (x) {
  return x + 1
}

function sub1 (x) {
  return x - 1
}

function add (x, y) {
  console.log('adding:', x, y)
  if (y === 0)
    return x
  else
    return add (add1(x), sub1(y))
}

function mult (x, y) {
  function aux (result, counter) {
    console.log('multiplying:', result, counter)
    if (counter === 0)
      return result
    else
      return aux (add(result, x), sub1(counter))
  }
  return aux (0, y)
}

console.log('result:', mult (5, 4)) // 20
```

And the same thing using undelimited continuations

```js
function add1 (x, k) {
  k (x + 1)
}

function sub1 (x, k) {
  k (x - 1)
}

function addk (x, y, k) {
  console.log('adding:', x, y)
  if (y === 0)
    k (x)
  else
    add1 (x, function (x1) {
      sub1 (y, function (y1) {
        addk (x1, y1, k)
      })
    })
}

function multk (x, y, k) {
  function aux (result, counter, k) {
    console.log('multiplying:', result, counter)
    if (counter === 0)
      k (result)
    else
      addk (result, x, function (result1) {
        sub1 (counter, function (counter1) {
          aux (result1, counter1, k)
        })
      })
  }
  aux (0, y, k)
}

multk (5, 4, function (result) { console.log('result:', result) /* 20 */ })
```